# How to get the destination folder while installing with apt module of Ansible?

Tags: ansible

In my ansible playbook, I installed openjdk with :

```
---
# tasks file related to java
- name: Install last version openjdk 8 jre
  apt:
    name: openjdk-8-jre
    state: latest
```

and I would like to set the `JAVA_HOME` env variable.

Is there a way to get the java folder to set my `JAVA_HOME` var ?

Thanks you ! :)

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use [lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) and proceed according to [How to set JAVA_HOME for Java?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java)

```
vars:
  my_users:
    - user1
    - user2
    - userN
  my_java_path: /usr/lib/jvm/open-jdk
tasks:
  - lineinfile:
      path: /etc/environment
      regexp: "^\\s*JAVA_HOME"
      line: "JAVA_HOME=\"{{ my_java_path }}\""
  - lineinfile:
      path: "/home/{{ item }}/.bashrc"
      line: "source /etc/environment"
    loop: "{{ my_users }}"
```

(not tested)

Comment: How can you set programmatically ? I mean your string `/usr/lib/jvm/...` is hardcoded so if my path for java is different.

Comment: I've updated the answer with the variable *my_java_path*. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable)